# Replace specific character with escaped version in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a large String with many occurrences like this:

```
List<String>
```

I need to convert that String so that it matches

```
List\<String\>
```

I was assuming that I would use the Java replaceAll("", "") method but I can't get it to work as I am not all that familiar with Regular expressions.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need four backslash characters, e.g.:

```
String input = "List<String>";
input = input.replaceAll("<", "\\\\<").replaceAll(">", "\\\\>");
```

`"\\\\<"` is the string literal for specifying `\\<`.

But why 2 `\` are necessary in the replacement string? Since the replacement string itself also has escape syntax (to escape `$`, which is used for specifying content in capturing group). `\<` (or as string literal `"\\<"`) is interpreted as `<` by the replace method. So we need to escape the `\` character at the replacement string level.

Comment: @Jon You need to escape the backslash itself so that the compiler accepts it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! 

My problem was with the "\\\\<"

Comment: You don't even need `replaceAll` in this case, you can just use a normal `replace` since you're not matching patterns.